# How to pass params in router using Vitest?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vitest

How can I passs params using Vitest for testing a vue component using composition api?
I tried that in the test file:

```
const wrapper = mount(EventDetails1, {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      $router: {
        params: { id: '8' },
      },
    }
  }
});
```

but i got the error undefined params inside the component when I tried to retrieve the params property: const {id} = route.params;

I'm using Vue3+quasar+Vitest as test runner

I hope a way to acommplish that